# Can bouyancy force result in action-reaction pair?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, fluid-statics, buoyancy

**Question**

When a body is immersed in an liquid the liquid exerts buoyant force on it. But does the body also exert a reaction force equal to the buoyant force on liquid as per Newtons 3rd law.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so what is buoyant force? It's the force that the displaced volume of the liquid applies to the body that displaces it. So, the buoyant force is actually a reaction by the liquid on the object that displaces it (the action).

Comment: Ok. But if for instance i have a container with water. If i put wood in it such that it floats and not sinks in it, would normal force due to container+ water increase or remain same?

Comment: How is container applying a force on the log? And by normal force, do you mean the buoyant force?

Comment: Nono  I mean the normal force that container + water system would exert on ground.

Comment: We can ask the following- How much force does the ground exert on this system? That's just the weight of the whole system- container+liquid+wood. Is that what you are asking?